# Responsividade no HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

escrevi meu portfólio a um tempo e tentei fazer ele ficar responsivo. Usei a técnica de Mobile First. Na resolução de celular ele ficou massa, mas quando fiz a primeira responsividade para resolução de 600px de largura, só funciona quando executo o código, quando coloco ele ativo, ele não fica responsivo.
Vou postar as imagens e o código pra que vcs possam me ajudar.
agradeço desde já!
[image: Essa imagem é da execução do código]
[image: Quando eu acesso o site com a mesma resolução usada para executar o código]

```css
/* ----------- RESET ----------- */
*{
 margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%; border: none; outline: none; font-weight: 300; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
body {
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
 list-style: none;
}
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

@charset "UTF-8";

body {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*CABEÇALHO*/

.top_down_bc{
 background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff, #00BFFF);
 width: 100%;
}

header.cabecalho {
 position: fixed; 
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding: 2% 3%; 
}


img#logo {
 width: 100%;
}

img#description {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 12.5% 5px 0 5px;
}

.btn-menu {
 width: 95%;
 height: 95%;
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 50px;
 cursor:pointer;
 background: linear-gradient(to right,#09e7a7,#2cbfc8);
}


/*  MENU */
.menu {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.btn-close {
 font-size: 3em; 
 color: #ffffff;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 5%;
}
.menu ul {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
 padding: 1.5%;
}
.menu li a {
 font-size: 2em;
 color: #fff; padding: 1.5% 3%;
}
.menu li a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2cbfc8;
}

.apresentations {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 20% 0 0 25%;
}

/* Apresentation */

div.banner {
 margin: 1% 0 0 0;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1% 5%;
 background: linear-gradient( to top, #58FA82, #58FAAC, #58FAD0);
 border-radius: 50px;
 line-height: 1.8em; 
}


p.coment {
 text-align: justify;
}

h1.titulo {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 700;
}

h2.coment {
 padding: 1% 0;
 font-weight: 600;
}

/* About Me */


button.btn-ensino { 
 transition: background-color 2s, font-size 1s;
 border: double 5px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 25%;
 padding: 5%;
 margin: 1% 0%;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #4169E1, #1E90FF, #00BFFF);
}

button.btn-ensino:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 text-shadow: 5px 5px #000;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 25%;
 padding: 8%;
 margin: 1% 0%;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #00BFFF, #1E90FF, #4169E1);
}

div#about_me {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3% 4%;
 background: linear-gradient(to top, #FFFF00, #FFD700, #FFA500, #FF8C00, #FF4500);
 border-radius: 50px; 
}

div.ensinos {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background: linear-gradient(to top, #000000, #696969, #808080);
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
h2.titulo_ensino {
 margin: 25% 0;
 color: #DCDCDC;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-weight: 980;
}

p.paragrafo_ensino {
 font-size: 1.1em;
}

div.ensino-tecnico {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
div.ensino-superior {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

button.btn-cert {
 transition: font-size 1s;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #696969, #808080, #A9A9A9);
 width: 100%;
 margin: 2% 0;
 padding: 5%;
 border-radius: 15px;
}

button.btn-cert:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #A9A9A9, #808080, #696969, #000);
 width: 100%;
 margin: 2% 0;
 padding: 5%;
 border-radius: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}

i.far {
 padding: 2%;
}

/* Exemplos de sites */

div#sites {
 background: linear-gradient(to top, #00FA9A, #00FF7F, #98FB98, #90EE90);
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 18px;
}
header#sites_titulo {
 margin: auto;
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-align: center;
}

img#img_banner {
 float: right;
 margin: auto;
}

button.btn-sites {
 transition: font-size 1s;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #696969, #808080, #A9A9A9);
 width: 100%;
 margin: 2% 0;
 padding: 5%;
 border-radius: 15px;
}

button.btn-sites:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #A9A9A9, #808080, #696969, #000);
 width: 100%;
 margin: 2% 0;
 padding: 5%;
 border-radius: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.3em; 
}

/* Contacts */

div#corpo {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8B0000, #FF4500, #FF8C00, #FFA500);
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 18px;
 padding: 5% 0;
}

table#tabela {
 width: 70%;
 margin: auto;
 border: double;
 border-radius: 25px;
 border-spacing: 20px;
}
th.titulos {
 border-bottom: solid 0.1em;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

#number_phone {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 800;
}

.link_dados {
 font-size: 3em;
 color: #191970;
 padding-left: 25%;
}

footer {
 margin-top: 10%;
}

.footer_information {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 800;
 padding: 2px;
}

/*================================Mobile First========================*/
/*================================ 600px ========================*/
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

 .top_down_bc{
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff, #00BFFF);
  width: 100%;
 }

 header.cabecalho {
  position: fixed; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0% 0%; 
 }


 img#logo {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
 }

 img#description {
  width: 60%;
  margin: -6% auto;
 }

 .btn-menu {
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#09e7a7,#2cbfc8);
 }
 /*  MENU */

 .menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }

 .btn-close {
  font-size: 3em; 
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5%;
 }
 .menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: -10% auto;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .menu li {
  padding: 1.5%;
 }
 .menu li a {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff; padding: 1.5% 3%;
 }
 .menu li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #2cbfc8;
 }

 .apresentations {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10% 0% 0% 40%;
 }
 /* Apresentation */

 div.banner {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5% 0%;
  background: linear-gradient( to top, #58FA82, #58FAAC, #58FAD0);
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
 }

 h1.titulo {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: 700;
 }

 h2.coment {
  padding: 1% 0;
  font-weight: 600;
 }

 /* About Me */


 button.btn-ensino { 
  transition: background-color 2s, font-size 1s;
  border: double 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 25%;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 1% 0%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4169E1, #1E90FF, #00BFFF);
 }

 button.btn-ensino:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px #000;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 25%;
  padding: 8%;
  margin: 1% 0%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00BFFF, #1E90FF, #4169E1);
 }

 div#about_me {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3% 4%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #FFFF00, #FFD700, #FFA500, #FF8C00, #FF4500);
  border-radius: 50px; 
 }

 div.ensinos {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000000, #696969, #808080);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
 h2.titulo_ensino {
  margin: 10% 25% 10% 25%;
  color: #DCDCDC;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 980;
 }

 p.paragrafo_ensino {
  font-size: 1.2em;
 }

 div.ensino-tecnico {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
 div.ensino-superior {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }

 p.paragrafo_certificado {
  text-align: center;
 }

 button.btn-cert {
  transition: font-size 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #696969, #808080, #A9A9A9);
  width: 30%;
  margin: 2% 35%;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 15px;
 }

 button.btn-cert:hover {
  transition: font-size 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #696969, #808080, #A9A9A9);
  width: 32%;
  margin: 2% 35%;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 15px;
 }

 i.far {
  padding: 2%;
 }

 /* Exemplos de sites */

 div#sites {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #00FA9A, #00FF7F, #98FB98, #90EE90);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 18px;
 }
 header#sites_titulo {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
 }

 img#img_banner {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
 }

 button.btn-sites {
  transition: font-size 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #696969, #808080, #A9A9A9);
  width: 50%;
  margin: 2% 25%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 15px;
 }

 button.btn-sites:hover {
  transition: font-size 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #696969, #808080, #A9A9A9);
  width: 51%;
  margin: 2% 25%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 15px; 
 }

 /* Contacts */

 div#corpo {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8B0000, #FF4500, #FF8C00, #FFA500);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 18px;
  padding: 5% 0;
 }

 table#tabela {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  border: double;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-spacing: 20px;
 }
 th.titulos {
  border-bottom: solid 0.1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
 }

 #number_phone {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
 }

 .link_dados {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #191970;
  padding-left: 40%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/> 
 <meta name="description" content="This page it's my portfolio. Here you can know me and see my specifications.">
 <meta name="keywords" content="portfolio, Harysson, Haryinfo, desenvolvimento, web"/>
 <meta name="robots" content="index, follows"/>
 <meta name="author" content="Harysson Soares"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Haryinfo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main_estilo.css"/> 
 <script language="javascript" src="JavaScript/funcoes.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous"/> 
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ultra" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="icon" href="_images/logo_home.png"/>
</head>
<body id="inicio">
 <header class="cabecalho top_down_bc">
  <a href="index.html" id="link_home"><img src="_images/logo_home.png" id="logo"/></a>
  <img src="_images/web_development.png" id="description">
  <button class="btn-menu" alt="Menu"> <i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg" id="menu_icon"></i></button>
  <nav class="menu">
   <a class="btn-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> </a>   
   <ul>
    <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/logo_home.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/logo_home.png')" class="list_menu"> <a href="#inicio" id="index" class="link_menu">HOME</a> </li>
    <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/about_me.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/main.png')" class="list_menu"> <a href="#img_about_me" id="link_sobre_mim" class="link_menu" target="">SOBRE MIM</a> </li>
    <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/meus_trabalhos.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/main.png')" class="list_menu"> <a href="#img_my_jobs" id="link_meus_trabalhos" class="link_menu">VITRINE DE SITES</a> </li>
    <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/contato.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/main.png')" class="list_menu"> <a href="#img_contacts" id="link_contatos" class="link_menu">CONTATOS</a> </li>
    <img src="_images/main.png" id="icone"/>
   </ul>   
  </nav>

  <script>
  $(".btn-menu").click(function(){
   $(".menu").show();
  });

  $(".btn-close").click(function(){
   $(".menu").hide();
  });
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).keydown(function(e){
       if (e.keyCode == 27){
           $(".menu").hide();
          }
      });
  });
  $(".menu").click(function(){
   $(".menu").hide();
  });
  

 </script> 
 </header>
 <div class="img_principal">
  <img src="_images/main.png"/ id="hi" class="apresentations"/>
 </div>
 <div class="banner">
  <h1 class="titulo">Bem vindo ao futuro</h1>
  <h2 class="coment">Quanto você gasta em um anúncio da sua empresa?</h2>
  <h2 class="coment">Qual o alcance do tipo de anúncio usado por sua empresa?</h2>
  <h2 class="coment">O sua empresa possui um site? Acha que ela representa bem a sua empresa?</h2>
  <h2 class="coment">Você acha que um site serve apenas como propaganda e portfolio para sua empresa?</h2>
 </div> 

 <div>
  <img src="_images/about_me.png" id="img_about_me" class="apresentations">
 </div>

 <div id="about_me">  
  <header id="cabecalho" class="topico">
   <h1 class="titulo">SOBRE MIM</h1>
  </header>
    <h2 class="coment">Meus conhecimentos</h2>
    <p class="paragrafo coment">Atualmente possuo conhecimento em HTML5, CSS e JavaScript para o desenvolvimento Web. Além de conhecimentos para desenvolvimento Web, também possuo conhecimento sobre SQL, para banco de dados, PHP e Java.Esse conhecimento foi adquirido através de cursos com certificação. Para conferir essa certificação, acesse o link acima com o nome "CERTIFICAÇÕES".</p>
    
    <h2 class="coment">Progresso Educacional</h1>
    <button id="btn-basico" class="btn-ensino">Ensino Básico <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
    <button id="btn-tecnico" class="btn-ensino">Ensino Técnico <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
    <button id="btn-superior" class="btn-ensino">Ensino Superior <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button> 
    
    <div id="ensino-basico" class="ensinos">
     <a class="btn-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
     <h2 id="ensino_basico" class="titulo_ensino">Ensino Básico (fundamental e médio)</h2>
     <p class="paragrafo_ensino">Todo meu ensino básico foi feito no Instituto Reis Magos (IRM). Escola privada que me deu bolsa desde a pre-escola, sobre a condição de manter notas boas e evitar as recuperações.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="ensino-tecnico" class="ensinos">
     <a class="btn-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
     <h2 id="ensino_tecnico" class="titulo_ensino">Ensino Técnico</h2>
     <p class="paragrafo_ensino">Atualmente estou cursando ensino técnico no Instituto Metrópole Digital (IMD). O IMD possui vínculo com UFRN e empresas do ramo da tecnologia, como Microsoft e CISCO.</p>
     <p class="paragrafo_ensino">Pretendo fazer o ensino superior na UFRN (Bacharel em Tecnologia da Informação - BTI), porém sempre estou estudando e fazendo cursos sobre desenvolvimento Web e demais tecnologias.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="ensino-superior" class="ensinos">
     <a class="btn-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
     <h2 id="ensino_superior" class="titulo_ensino">Ensino Superior</h2>
     <p class="paragrafo_ensino">Minha formação é em Bacharel Ciências Biológicas, com ênfase em microbiologia. Essa área me trouxe muitos questionamentos sobre a Biotecnologia, o que me levou a estudar mais sobre programação.</p>
    </div>


    <script>
     $("#btn-basico").click(function(){
      $("#ensino-basico").show();
     });
     $(".btn-close").click(function(){
      $("#ensino-basico").hide();
     });
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).keydown(function(e){
          if (e.keyCode == 27){
              $("#ensino-basico").hide();
             }
         });
     });
     $("#btn-tecnico").click(function(){
      $("#ensino-tecnico").show();
     });
     $(".btn-close").click(function(){
      $("#ensino-tecnico").hide();
     });
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).keydown(function(e){
          if (e.keyCode == 27){
              $("#ensino-tecnico").hide();
             }
         });
     });
     $("#btn-superior").click(function(){
      $("#ensino-superior").show();
     });
     $(".btn-close").click(function(){
      $("#ensino-superior").hide();
     });
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).keydown(function(e){
          if (e.keyCode == 27){
              $("#ensino-superior").hide();
             }
         });
     });
    </script>

   <section id="da_biologia_para_tecnologia" class="topico">
    <h2 class="coment">Da Biologia para Tecnologia</h2>

    <p class="paragrafo coment">Diante de vários questionamentos sobre a mudança de área, ou mesmo qual a relação entre elas, a resposta é bem simples. O ramo da Biotecnologia me fez ver que no Brasil há uma carência muito grande do uso e do desenvolvimento de ferramentas tecnológicas. Acredito que vai além do ramo da biologia. A carência de programadores é muito grande, e isso não só no Brasil, mas no mundo inteiro. Então fica claro ver que não só a Biologia possui relação com a tecnologia, mas todas as áreas convergem para ela.</p>
   </section>

   <section id="certificacoes" class="topico">
    <h2 class="coment">Certificações</h2>
    <p class="paragrafo_certificado">HTML, CSS e JavaScript:<a href="_images/HTML5.jpg" target="_blank"><button class="btn-cert">Certificado<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i></button></a></p>
    <p class="paragrafo_certificado">Java:<a href="_images/certificado Java.pdf" target="_blank"><button class="btn-cert"> Certificado<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i></button></a></p>
    <p class="paragrafo_certificado">Montagem e Manutenção de computadores:<a href="_images/certificado Montagem e Manutenção de computadores.pdf" target="_blank"><button class="btn-cert">Certificado<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i></button></a></p>
    <p class="paragrafo_certificado">Congresso Online de Tecnologia da Informação:<a href="_images/Certificado TI.pdf" target="_blank"><button class="btn-cert">Certificado<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i></button></a></p>
   </section>
 </div>

 <div id="my_jobs">
  <img src="_images/meus_trabalhos.png" id="img_my_jobs" class="apresentations" />
  
  <div id="sites">
   <img src="_images/projects.png" id="img_banner"/> 
   <header id="sites_titulo">
    <h1 id="titulo">Sites criados por mim</h1>
   </header>
   <section id="lista_sites">
    <h2 id="google_glass"> <a href="projeto-glass-html5/index_google_glass.html"  class="link_sites" target="_blank" onmouseover="mudaFotoMyJobs('_images/google-glasses_mobile.png')" onmouseout="mudaFotoMyJobs('_images/projects.png')"><button class="btn-sites" id="btn-google-glass"> Site sobre Google Glass <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></button></a></h2>

    <h2 id="cpc"> <a href="Site_CPC/index_CPC.html" class="link_sites" target="_blank" onmouseout="mudaFotoMyJobs('_images/projects.png')" onmouseover="mudaFotoMyJobs('Site_CPC/image/logo_CPC_200x200_mobile.png')"><button class="btn-sites" id="btn-cpc"> Site para o Centro Pedagógico de Candelária (CPC)<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></button></a></h2>

    <h2 id="hi"> <a href="index.html" class="link_sites" target="_blank" onmouseout="mudaFotoMyJobs('_images/projects.png')" onmouseover="mudaFotoMyJobs('_images/logo_home_mobile.png')"><button class="btn-sites" id="btn-home"> Este que vos é apresentado(Hi Tech)<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></button></a></h2>

    <h2> <p onmouseout="mudaFotoMyJobs('_images/projects.png')" onmouseover="mudaFotoMyJobs('_images/emoticon_mobile.png')"> <button class="btn-sites" id="btn-nothing-do">O Próximo da lista, poderia ser sua empresa!</button></p></h2>  
   </section>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="contacts">
  <img src="_images/contato.png" id="img_contacts" class="apresentations"/>
  <div id="corpo">
   <table id="tabela">
    <tr class="linha_titulo">
     <th class="titulos" colspan="2">Telefone/WhatsApp</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linha_information">
     <td colspan="2" class="dados"><h1 id="number_phone">(84)99819-0309</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linha_titulo">
     <th class="titulos" colspan="2">Redes Sociais</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linha_information">
     <td class="dados"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011284782564" target="_blank" class="link_dados" onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/facebook.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/contato.png')"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square facebook"></i></a></td>
     <td class="dados"><a href="https://twitter.com/haryssonsoares" target="_blank" class="link_dados" onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/twitter.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/contato.png')"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square twitter"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linha_titulo">
     <th class="titulos" colspan="2">Redes Profissionais</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linha_information">
     <td class="dados"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/harysson-soares-96476099/" target="_blank" class="link_dados" onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/linkedin.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/contato.png')"><i class="fab fa-linkedin linkedin"></i></a></td>
     <td class="dados"><a href="https://github.com/Rharuow" target="_blank" class="link_dados" onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/github.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/contato.png')"><i class="fab fa-github-square github"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="rodape">
  <footer class="top_down_bc">
   <h1 class="footer_information">Todos direitos reservados por:</h1>
   <h1 class="footer_information"><i class="far fa-copyright"></i>HI Tech Web Development</h1>
   <h1 class="footer_information">Last Update: 26/05/2018</h1>
  </footer>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saudações, Harysson; seja bem-vindo ao site. Como é novo, sugiro que faça o [tour] para aprender o básico do funcionamento da comunidade e leia o guia de [ask]. Busque descrever melhor qual é o seu problema e leia sobre como elaborar um [mcve] para reduzir a complexidade da sua pergunta e focar somente naquilo que é necessário.

Comment: Leia aqui e aprenda a usar media queries de forma correta
https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/